# Drag and drop operations in Office word web addin

Tags: office-js

I have some icons in my addin taskpane. I would like to drag and drop them onto my word document one at a time or maybe multiple at a time. Are drag and drop operations supported in the Office js API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not supported at this time. Please consider suggesting it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).